# How to return the result of an observable

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I just want to return the result of the subscription (which is an array) to the `getData` function.

i have a component which depends on the return value of the getData method to function

```
import { ReportsService } from './../../../../../../services/reports.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-cardyesterday',
  templateUrl: './cardyesterday.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cardyesterday.component.css']
})
export class CardyesterdayComponent implements OnInit {
  salesCounter: any;
  amountCounter: any;
  changeCounter: any;
  changePeople: any;
  constructor(private report: ReportsService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    const d = this.report.getData();
  }


}
```

here is the service

```
import { AuthService } from './auth.service'; 
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({ 
    providedIn: 'root' 
}) 
export class ReportsService { 
    user: String; 
    constructor(private authService: AuthService) { } 
    getData() { 
        this.authService.getSales().subscribe(d => { 
            this.user = d.data; 
        }, 
        error => console.log(`error is ${error}`), 
        this.hh.bind(this)); 
        return this.user 
    } 

    hh() { 
        return this.user 
    } 
}
```

so how do i get the getData method in ReportsService to return the value of the subscription( which is an array)

Comment: You cannot do this.  Please provide your use case, and perhaps someone can help you consider another solution of value.  Off the bat, you could have getData return an Observable (or Promise), which will be resolved, when user is resolved.

Comment: Thanks for replying, i have a component which needs the getData method to return an array of products . if you say i can do that, please how do i return the result from the subscription? so i can use it in the component

Comment: You were setting the response to this.user. you do not need to return it

Answer (score 3):

```
import { AuthService } from './auth.service'; 
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({ 
    providedIn: 'root' 
}) 
export class ReportsService { 
    user: String; 
    constructor(private authService: AuthService) { } 
    getData() { 
        return this.authService.getSales();
    } 

    hh() { 
        return this.user 
    } 
}
```

component

```
import { ReportsService } from './../../../../../../services/reports.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-cardyesterday',
  templateUrl: './cardyesterday.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cardyesterday.component.css']
})
export class CardyesterdayComponent implements OnInit {
  salesCounter: any;
  amountCounter: any;
  changeCounter: any;
  changePeople: any;
  constructor(private report: ReportsService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    subscription = this.report.getData().subscribe(data => { do something});
  }        
}
```

call subscription.unsubscribe() wherever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you return the Observable and subscribe to it wherever you actually need the data it emits.

Comment: how do i do this, i have a component which needs the getData method to return an array of products . if you say i can do that, please how do i return the result from the subscription? so i can use it in the component –

Comment: @ayotycoon You subscribe in the component to the Observable you return from getData

Comment: The getData method returns an observeable. i want the getData method to return the values of the subscription which is an array from the observeable in this.authService

Comment: @ayotycoon I think you need to check out some RxJS tutorials because I think you haven't understood the concept yet. You can't just return the value of the Observable in the way you want, because there is no value you can immediately return. Your observable looks asynchronous, so there is no value to return when the method is called, as the observable might emit a value in any point in time. Also which value do you want to return? The principle of observables say, that it can emit multiple values. Which value should it return? First, second, third? Checkout some tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

You have to **return** the data as such

```
getData(): Observable<YOUR_DATA_TYPE> { 
        this.authService.getSales().subscribe(d => { 
            return this.user = d.data; 
        }, 
etc..
```

and in your `TS` file you would

```
this.report.getData().subscribe( (response) => {
   this.user = response.data;
});
```

Comment: I understand what you are doing, but you are not returning anything in the first codeblock. That's why the user is getting errors I imagine.

Answer (score 0):

so i finally got it.
First i created a method in my service that returns a promise

```
fetcher() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.authService.getSales().subscribe(d => {
        this.server = d.data;
        resolve();
      });
    });
  }
```

then in my main entry method( actual function that gets called), i used asyc await function to wait for the promise and then continue executing the code

```
async getSalesCounter(n) {
    const data = this.dateService.getDate();
    const date = data.split('|')[0];
    const day = data.split('|')[1];
    const month = data.split('|')[2];
    const year = data.split('|')[3];
    const finalUdate = parseInt(`${year}${month}${date}`, 10);

    await this.fetcher();
    const temp = {
      salesCounter: 0,
      amountCounter: 0,
      changeCounter: 0,
      changePeople: 0,
      products: []
    };
    this.server.forEach(serv => {
      const Sdate = serv.date.split('|')[0];
      const Sday = serv.date.split('|')[1];
      const Smonth = serv.date.split('|')[2];
      const Syear = serv.date.split('|')[3];
      const finalServerDate = parseInt(`${Syear}${Smonth}${Sdate}`, 10);

      const calcResult = finalUdate - finalServerDate;
      if (calcResult === n) {
        temp.salesCounter = this.todaySales();
        temp.amountCounter += serv.price;
        temp.products.push(serv);
        if (serv.change > 0) {
          temp.changeCounter += serv.change;
          temp.changePeople = this.countChange();
        }
      }
    });
    this.salesCounter = temp.salesCounter;
    this.amountCounter = temp.amountCounter;
    this.changeCounter = temp.changeCounter;
    this.changePeople = temp.changePeople;
    const details = {
      salesCounter: this.salesCounter,
      amountCounter: this.amountCounter,
      changeCounter: this.changeCounter,
      changePeople: this.changePeople,
      products: temp.products
    };
    this.salesCounter = 0;
    this.changePeople = 0;
    return details;
  }
```

Thanks Everyone for your contributions, gave me opportunity to read more so i learnt more too !